# Blazor Server Side - hosting

Tags: asp.net, firebase, hosting, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am wondering is there a way to host a Blazor Server-Side app on something like Firebase or Netlify, because when I publish my Blazor Server-Side app there is no dist folder with the main index.html like in the Client Side?

Answer (score 0):

Blazor Server requires ASP.NET Core support and SignalR. Your hosting must support ASP.NET Core with WebSockets / Long Polling.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-3.1